# geometric distribution of mistrials between two hits

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I have the following Task to complete:

A Basketball Player has 10 tries.
The table below shows the amount $x_k$ of mistrials till the $k^{th}$ success:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Trial \ k   & 1 & 2  & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\ \hline
x_k & 1 & 0  & 2 & 3 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 2   \\ \hline
\end{array}

Which distribution does the amount of mistrials $x_k$ have between two hits?

We got as far as to argue:

1. The event of X (the player has scored a hit) is bernoulli distributed; since 
   $x \in \{1,0\} $
2. Since $ X_1, ...,X_n $ are independent repetitions of $X$, they should be 
   geometrical distributed. (So $ X_1, ...,X_n $ is the Amount of failed attempts 
   until the first hit)

Now I seem to be unable to find a way to continue the argument.

Are our assumptions correct?

Do I need to introduce another Event for the next hit to come?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your assumptions are correct. The $x_k$-s are indeed geometrically distributed. Introducing another event would be wrong since you want to strictly study your given sample and its sample space.

Comment: Hey thanks for your quick response!
So the distribution of the mistrials between two hits is also geometrically distributed? It appears to me that the task is asking for an argument based on the difference between the a geometric distribution and in this case one, that applies to the failed attempts between the hits, though I fail to understand the difference, since the probability should be the same in my opinion.
thanks for helping me out here :)